# Multiple jQuery selectors, with IDs start with specific characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am facing this problem inside my third party application. now the third party application generated ids for my text fields and checkboxes as follow:-

```
ItemQuickOrder_a91a0ce2-7fb6-4c9c-97f5-e851cf4f10a6_MultiChoiceOption_0
ItemRequired_1817888e-9d2e-4ad6-87a0-1713c7b7dd97_MultiChoiceOption_0
ItemOneOffCost_ef64a5b1-07e1-40ce-8c80-2f2ace717b4f_$CurrencyField
ItemMonthlyReoccurringCost_f60c47be-2361-47eb-92f5-9b4ec7a0c057_$CurrencyField
ItemAnnualRecurringCost_db2c2537-e1b9-40bf-badc-a09637616aaa_$CurrencyField
```

so now I want to write a jQuery function, which get fired when the above text and checkboxes are changed (someone enter a character inside a text field, or check/uncheck a checkbox). So I wrote this test function:-

```
$("#ItemQuickOrder_a91a0ce2-7fb6-4c9c-97f5-e851cf4f10a6_MultiChoiceOption_0,
#ItemRequired_1817888e-9d2e-4ad6-87a0-1713c7b7dd97_MultiChoiceOption_0,
#ItemOneOffCost_ef64a5b1-07e1-40ce-8c80-2f2ace717b4f_$CurrencyField,
#ItemMonthlyReoccurringCost_f60c47be-2361-47eb-92f5-9b4ec7a0c057_$CurrencyField,
#ItemAnnualRecurringCost_db2c2537-e1b9-40bf-badc-a09637616aaa_$CurrencyField").change(function() 
{
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

but I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

Now I think this error is related to the fact that my jQuery selector are being entered inside multiple lines. so i tried to split them, but i got an error that i can not have `$` inside my ids.

So my question is how i can make my jQuery script more readable, but selecting my items based on their IDs starting with specific charrecters, as my IDS will have unique characters starting with "ItemQuickOrder" OR "ItemRequired", etc..

Comment: You may not use newlines inside the string.

Comment: @MEE i am using notepad ++ and it will automatically split them in new lines.. also this will nto fix the problem that i can not have `$` inside the id..

Comment: The Problem you report is *only* caused by the problem I explained you in my comment. AFAIK Notepad++ is not splitting it into new lines but just wraps the text. In your code snippet the code is split into lines.

Comment: Use the [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

Comment: @billyonecan but `starts with` will return an array of elements, and i am unable to find a way to have multiple jQuery selectors using `start with`..

Comment: `[id^="ItemQuickOrder"], [id^="ItemRequired"], [id^="ItemOneOffCost"], ...` ?

Comment: @billyonecan but when i wrote my selector as `$([id^="ItemQuickOrder"], [id^="ItemRequired"], [id^="ItemOneOffCost"], [id^="ItemMonthlyReoccurringCost"], [id^="ItemAnnualRecurringCost"]).change(function(){` i got an exception `id is not defined`

Comment: You need to wrap your selector in quotes `$('[id^="ItemQuickOrder"], [id^="ItemRequired"], ...')`

Comment: @billyonecan yes correct i missed the quotes.... so is this approach universally acceptable among browsers ? second point now when i am selecting based in id start with certain characters, what will happen if i have multiple ids which match? will jQuery select the first match by default ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way I would do it that seems a little more readable to me.

```
let idsBeginWith = [
  "ItemQuickOrder",
  "ItemRequired",
  "ItemOneOffCost",
  "ItemMonthlyReoccurringCost",
  "ItemAnnualRecurringCost"
];
// ES6
$(idsBeginWith.map(e=>`[id^="${e}"]`).join(",")).change(function(){
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
// ES5
$(idsBeginWith.map(function(e){ return '[id^="'+e+'"]';}).join(",")).change(function(){
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Comment: G your approach worked for me, i test it on IE.. will this be supported on all browsers?or there are limitations?

Comment: Template literals are not supported in IE11, but are in Edge. To support IE11 you could use `['id^="'+e+'"]'` instead. `Array.map` is pretty much universally supported.

Comment: browser would need to implement ES6 as well (i think that's when arrow functions were introduced, could be wrong though)

Comment: Oh whoops I completely forgot about the arrow function haha

Comment: Why couldn't windows 7 support edge.. *sighs*

Comment: @CodyG. so will ES5 woks on Edge ? or i need to have both appraochies ? to cover Edge and IE 11??

Comment: ES5 should work on everything :) (within reason...probably not netscape) --- I like this website for checking features. https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20function

Comment: @CodyG. but on IE11 i am getting this error `Expected ';'` at the `let` array

Comment: I don't have any problems in IE11.  ;(

Comment: You can get that error if you don't end: `let idsBeginWith = [];` <- with a semicolon...

Comment: @CodyG. but i am ending this.. and it is working on firefox and chrome.. but not on IE..

Comment: You could try using `var` but that shouldn't make a difference... unless you are scoping the variable different than shown or you're using IE10 or below. (You're also removing the ES6 code, right?... would get a syntax error otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape $ with a \, also you can use \ at the end of a string to define a string on multiple lines.(the newlines are not part of the string however)

```
$("#ItemQuickOrder_a91a0ce2-7fb6-4c9c-97f5-e851cf4f10a6_MultiChoiceOption_0,\
#ItemRequired_1817888e-9d2e-4ad6-87a0-1713c7b7dd97_MultiChoiceOption_0,\
#ItemOneOffCost_ef64a5b1-07e1-40ce-8c80-2f2ace717b4f_\\$CurrencyField,\
#ItemMonthlyReoccurringCost_f60c47be-2361-47eb-92f5-9b4ec7a0c057_\\$CurrencyField,\
#ItemAnnualRecurringCost_db2c2537-e1b9-40bf-badc-a09637616aaa_\\$CurrencyField").change(function() 
{
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Comment: but can i make my code more readable, and have my jQuery selectors based on `start with`??

Comment: using `\` has fixed the issue,,, but not sure if i can use `start with`

Comment: You can if only the elements you're selecting start with `Item` since that's all they have in common

Comment: no i mean instead of selecting an item based on its full id as follow `#ItemQuickOrder_a91a0ce2-7fb6-4c9c-97f5-e851cf4f10a6_MultiChoiceOption_0` can i select this item using its first charecters `itemQuickOrder`??

Comment: You mean like `$("[id^=ItemQuickOrder], ...` ? sure, I was talking about `$("[id^=Item]")`